# How to implement a queue using RxJS?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm designing an API (in NodeJS) which receives a list of user ids, for instance, and access Google Firebase's API to send a notification to those users.

Considering Firebase having a quota limit on how many requests you can concurrently send to, I buffered the Ids and send the requests one by one to Firebase with a delay of two seconds. Here's some simplified sample code for explanation:

```
app.post('/send-request', (req, res, next) =>{
  const userIds = req.body.userIds;
  ‎const streams = userIds.map((userId) => {
‎    return Observable
‎      .fromPromise(fetch(`firebase url`, {
‎          method: 'POST', 
‎          headers: ..., 
          body: ... 
‎        }))
‎        .delay(2000) 
‎        .retryWhen(attempts => { 
‎          return attempts.zip(Rx.Observable.range(1, 4))
            .mergeMap(([error, i]) => { 
              if (i > 3) { 
                return Rx.Observable.throw(error); 
            } 
              console.log(`Wait ${i} seconds, then retry!`); 
              return Rx.Observable.timer(i * 1000); 
            });
      ‎  });
  });


  const stream = Observable.merge(...streams);
‎  stream.subscribe();
});
```

This can handle the case when a single request consists of a lot of users. However, if my API receives similar requests concurrently, it's bound to fail.

Therefore, I want to buffer all these user ids in a queue where this queue can keep receiving more and more user ids an buffer them, and at the same time 'top' the queue by sending requests to Firebase at a steady rate. However, I don't know how to do it with RxJS. Do I have to use an Scheduler? Or is there actually a better solution than using Rx?

Note: I understand Javascript is single-threaded so it's not exactly concurrency, I only used this word so you can get the idea better.

Comment: Can you use `Rx.Observable.timer()`?http://jsfiddle.net/jorgenfb/fa586f4m/

Comment: @Neel What if you have to handle multiple requests like this at the same time? Then you will have multiple timers that also send requests almost at the same time at the same rate, which still floods Firebase with requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to come up with something, the key part is to use `Subject` to publish values, then use the `zip` operator to emit value on a regular interval. It'd be even better if I can take the values on demand, but the current solution is already much better than my original method.

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
const stream = subject
  .zip(Rx.Observable.interval(3000), function(a, b) { return a; });

stream.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log(`onNext: ${val}`); },  
  (e) => { console.log(`onError: ${e}`); },
  () => { console.log('onCompleted'); });
```

I used VueJS to build a simple web page for a little demo.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    subject: undefined,
    stream: undefined,
    count: 0,
    emitHistory: [],
    disableBtn: true
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created');
    this.subject = new Rx.Subject();
    this.stream = this.subject
      .zip(Rx.Observable.interval(3000), function(a, b) { return a; })
      // .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.queue); // not working
    this.stream.subscribe(
     (val) => { 
       console.log(`onNext: ${val}`);
        this.emitHistory.push(val);
        if (val === this.count) {
         this.disableBtn = false;
        } else {
         this.disableBtn = true;
        }
      },
      (e) => { console.log(`onError: ${e}`); },
      () => { console.log('onCompleted'); });
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler() {
      this.count++;
      this.subject.onNext(this.count);
    },
    clear() {
     this.count = 0;
      this.emitHistory = [];
    }
  }
});

/* 
Rx.Observable
  .fromArray([1,2,3])
  .zip(Rx.Observable.interval(500), function(a, b) { return a; })
  .subscribe(
    function(x) { document.write(x + '<br \>'); },  
    null,  
    function() { document.write("complete"); }); 
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="clickHandler()">Click me</button>
  <button @click="clear()" v-bind:disabled="disableBtn">Clear</button>
  <div>
    <h5>Count: {{count}}</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, idx) in emitHistory" v-bind:key="idx">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```